# interp2d function in Python runtime error

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have the following data which in MATLAB is easily being interpolated using the `interp2` function. However in Python with the use of interp2d, the following error encounters:

```
RuntimeWarning: No more knots can be added because the number of B-spline
coefficients already exceeds the number of data points m.
Probable causes: either s or m too small. (fp>s)
    kx,ky=3,3 nx,ny=17,11 m=90 fp=0.000013 s=0.000000
  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))
```

I have tried to use `griddata`, but no luck in that end either.
Any fix to these issues would be much appreciated.

**CODE:**

```
OF_S = np.array([[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5],
                 [6, 6, 6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6, 6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6],
                 [7, 7, 7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7]])

FT_FTAVAIL_S = np.array([[0.198,     0.205,     0.214,     0.227,     0.237,     0.249,     0.26,     0.271,     0.285,     0.304,     0.332,     0.371,     0.405,     0.436,     0.464,     0.507,     0.548,     0.598,     0.649,     0.694,     0.746,     0.787,     0.822,     0.851,     0.879,     0.914,     0.951,     0.985,     0.999,     1],
                         [0.198,     0.205,     0.214,     0.227,     0.237,     0.249,     0.26,     0.271,     0.285,     0.304,     0.332,     0.371,     0.405,     0.436,     0.464, 0.507,     0.548,     0.598,     0.649,     0.694,     0.746,     0.787,     0.822,     0.851,     0.879,     0.914,     0.951,     0.985,     0.999,     1],
                         [0.198,     0.205,     0.214,     0.227,     0.237,     0.249,     0.26,     0.271,     0.285,     0.304,     0.332,     0.371,     0.405,     0.436,     0.464,     0.507,     0.548,     0.598,     0.649,     0.694,     0.746,     0.787,     0.822,     0.851,     0.879,     0.914,     0.951,     0.985,     0.999,     1.000]])

ISP_ISPAVAIL_S = np.array([[0.9845,     0.9867,     0.9867,     0.9867,     0.9867,     0.9889,     0.9889,     0.9889,     0.9889,     0.9911,     0.9911,     0.9933,     0.9933,     0.9956,     0.9956,     0.9956,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     1,     1,     1,     1],
                           [0.9756,     0.9756,     0.9761,     0.9778,     0.9778,     0.9778,     0.9787,     0.9798,     0.98,     0.9804,     0.9827,     0.9844,     0.9855,     0.9867, 0.9889,     0.9892,     0.9911,     0.9927,     0.9933,     0.9942,     0.9956,     0.9956,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9978,     0.9988,     1,     1,     1],
                           [0.9662,     0.9662,     0.9662,     0.9679,     0.9685,     0.9697,     0.9707,     0.9709,     0.972,     0.9738,     0.9755,     0.9797,     0.9805,     0.982,     0.9842,     0.9863,     0.9873,     0.9887,     0.991,     0.992,     0.9932,     0.9943,     0.9955,     0.9955,     0.9966,     0.9977,     0.9978,     0.9986,     0.9999,     1]])

ISP_ISPAVAIL_interpGrid = interp2d(FT_FTAVAIL_S, OF_S, ISP_ISPAVAIL_S, kind='cubic')
```

Comment: [`ISP_ISPAVAIL_S` needs to be a _function_ of `OF_S` and `FT_FTAVAIL_S`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

Comment: @DrBwts could you give an example please

Comment: click on the link in my last comment it has a very clear example of usage that I couldnt in all honesty improve on.

Comment: @DrBwts the link has `z` as `z = np.sin(xx**2+yy**2)`. This isn't a function of `xx` and `yy` really, it's an array with the same dimensions. In the OP `ISP_ISPAVAIL_S` is also an array like that so I am also not sure how you would make it a function of the other two?

Comment: yes but the interpolation function your are calling is NOT expecting you do have done the interpolation, thats the whole point of using it. If you already have the`z` values at `(x, y)` why bother using `scipy.interp2d()`?

Comment: also `np.sin(xx**2+yy**2)` really is a function

Comment: I ended up using griddata since interp2d was returning different size arrays. I believe comparing the results to MATLAB griddata gave me a closer value than interp2d

Comment: @DrBwts in Python it isn't a function, it's an array. Consider that `z` are empirical measurements, the point of interpolation is that you don't know the function but you know the values at some points. In this case, you use `interp2` to fit a function to the data so that you can interpolate to points in between the `xx` and `yy` coordinates that you knew the `z`s for. What the OP has done is identical to the example in the docs.

Comment: @Kevin_ALA you should post an answer to your own question if you've solved it, for future readers.

Comment: @Dan please take a look at the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using griddata instead. The key here is to have flattened data before any interpolation. Therefore I used the .ravel() to do so.

```
ISP_ISPAVAIL= griddata(
        (FT_FTAVAIL_S.ravel(), OF_S.ravel()), ISP_ISPAVAIL_S.ravel(), (XX, YY), method="nearest")
```

where XX and YY are some arbitrary bounds for FT_FTAVAIL_S and OF_S respectively.